# JQuery One Code For Multiple Button Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not using ID's instead of classes. I have multiple buttons with similar classes and only one JQuery code.

It is chessboardjs javascript code.

The problem that I am facing is different for the two different buttons.

For the Reset button, when I click the top button, the lower embed gets reset too. However, not vice versa.

For the Show Answer button, when I click any one of them, it works simultaneously for all the buttons.

What I want is, they must work independently of one another.

Here's the JQuery and HTML code.

```js
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".formButton").click(function(){
            $(".answer_text").toggle();
        });
    });</script>
```

```html
<center>
    <div id="board1" style="width: 450px"></div>
    <p><b>Kramnik vs Igor Saric, Leningrad, 1991<br>(White to move)</b></p>
    <input type="button" class="anyButton setPosition" value="Reset" />
    <button type="button" class="anyButton formButton">Show Answer!</button>&nbsp;<span class="description answer_text">Qxf6+ w/Rxe6+</span>
</center>
<script>
    var cfg = {
      position: '2r5/pp3k2/2q1br1p/3pQ3/3P2P1/1P2R3/P7/1B2R1K1 w - -',
      draggable:true
    };
    var board1 = ChessBoard('board1', cfg);
    $('.setPosition').on('click', function() {
      var inPosition = '2r5/pp3k2/2q1br1p/3pQ3/3P2P1/1P2R3/P7/1B2R1K1 w - -';
      board1.position(inPosition);
      });
</script>
&nbsp;
<center>
    <div id="board2" style="width: 450px"></div>
    <p><b>Grischuk vs Andrey Lunev, Moscow, 1999<br>(White to move)</b></p>
    <input type="button" class="anyButton setPosition" value="Reset" />
    <button type="button" class="anyButton formButton">Show Answer!</button>&nbsp;<span class="description answer_text">Ne5+ Kh4 Qh6+ Kg3 Qxg5+ & Nd3+</span>
</center>
<script>
    var cfg = {
      position: '8/p4p2/3RbQ2/2q3p1/4P1k1/P4N2/2r5/7K w - - 0 1',
      draggable:true
    };
    var board2 = ChessBoard('board2', cfg);
    $('.setPosition').on('click', function() {
      var inPosition = '8/p4p2/3RbQ2/2q3p1/4P1k1/P4N2/2r5/7K w - - 0 1';
      board2.position(inPosition);
      });
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about what you're trying to achieve/describe here.  You're assigning a click function twice to all elements with a class of `.setPosition`. Is that your intent? Also, do you understand the [in]significance of embedding two separate in-line `<script>` tags?  Are you trying to accomplish something peculiar with that?

Comment: i think you need to see the webpage here: iplaychess.club/puzzles. The board is interactive (you can move the pieces). The 'Show Answer' must show the answer for the specific puzzle. The 'Reset' button should reset the position to the former position. Can you please help me out with writing the <script> tags only once?

Comment: I think we need to know what `ChessBoard();` does

Comment: It's load of code in there. You can check out the software here: chessboardjs.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because of using the same variable in JS code for both boards, I mean var "inPosition"....as the variable the same, that is why when you click to "Reset" you set the same positions for both of them....try to change the var to "inPosition2" for the second board

Answer (score 0):

You have other problems here that I would recommend working on, but to answer your direct question this should do it.

If you click the show answer button it only shows the answer that is the same sibling of the button.

**This is the specific code changed within the snippet:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".formButton").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".answer_text").toggle();
  });
});
```

**Full Working Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".formButton").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".answer_text").toggle();
  });
});

//Your other scripts
var cfg = [{
    position: '2r5/pp3k2/2q1br1p/3pQ3/3P2P1/1P2R3/P7/1B2R1K1 w - -',
    draggable: true
  },
  {
    position: '8/p4p2/3RbQ2/2q3p1/4P1k1/P4N2/2r5/7K w - - 0 1',
    draggable: true
  }
];

var board1 = ChessBoard('board1', cfg[0]);
var board2 = ChessBoard('board2', cfg[1]);

$('.setPosition').on('click', function() {
  var inPosition = ['2r5/pp3k2/2q1br1p/3pQ3/3P2P1/1P2R3/P7/1B2R1K1 w - -', '8/p4p2/3RbQ2/2q3p1/4P1k1/P4N2/2r5/7K w - - 0 1'];

  //New Code to avoid "Position Undefined" error in Snippet
  if (typeof page_name != 'undefined') {

    //Original StandAlone Code
    board1.position(inPosition[0]);
    board2.position(inPosition[1]);

    //Note: Not sure if this error is happen because the full "ChessBoard" function is not avalible or if there is a typo/misstake in your coding. I implemented an error check here so the snippet doesnt bug out.

  } else {

    alert('Cannot retrieve "position" of undefined variable.');

  }
});

//Avoid "ChessBoard();" Error in Snippet
function ChessBoard(BoardID, cfgCode) {
  var returnResults = document.getElementById('returnResults');
  returnResults.innerHTML += '<table><tr><th>BoardID</th><th>cfgCode</th></tr><tr><td>' + BoardID + '</td><td>' + cfgCode.position + '</td></tr></table>'
}

//More Testing
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = board1;
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = board2;
```

```css
.board {
  width: 450px;
}


/* For Testing only (These can be deleted for final product, dont forget to delete the classes within the HTML file) */

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.responsive-table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center class="box">
  <div id="board1" class="board"></div>
  <p><b>Kramnik vs Igor Saric, Leningrad, 1991<br>(White to move)</b></p>
  <input type="button" class="anyButton setPosition" value="Reset" />
  <button type="button" class="anyButton formButton">Show Answer!</button>
  <span class="description answer_text">Qxf6+ w/Rxe6+</span>
</center>

<center class="box">
  <div id="board2" class="board"></div>
  <p><b>Grischuk vs Andrey Lunev, Moscow, 1999<br>(White to move)</b></p>
  <input type="button" class="anyButton setPosition" value="Reset" />
  <button type="button" class="anyButton formButton">Show Answer!</button>
  <span class="description answer_text">Ne5+ Kh4 Qh6+ Kg3 Qxg5+ & Nd3+</span>
</center>

<!-- For Testing Only -->
<div id="Testing" class="box">
  <h3>"ChessBoard" Results:</h3>
  <div id="returnResults" class="responsive-table"></div>

  <h3>Variable Results:</h3>
  <div><b>Variable "board1" Returned: </b><span id="test1"></span></div>
  <div class="pt-1"><b>Variable "board2" Returned: </b><span id="test2"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you just hint at the other issues? Would love an opinion. Thanks. And what is the other code that you added?

Comment: I have a question. If I use multiple scripts within the body html, what is the consequence? Instead of adding them before </body>?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got off for the day. Some other issues were mentioned in the comments, like using multiple Script elements within your page. When you do this the page has to stop loading everything else to process this information. and in your case they could be simplified into one script element and recommended to be placed and the bottom of the body. This is so the page can load everything else and then process the information within the script. The next best thing to do would be move it to its own file like `main.js` and link it at the end of the body. (Continued....)

Comment: The next thing is the fact that you have variables that share the same name when executed, `var cfg` and  `var inPosition`. If you noticed my temp code that I inserted into the document to void the `ChessBoard();` returns only the information for the second board everytime. This is because they both fire at the same time and with no unique variable name it will also rewrite the previous value. So when you tell your code `cfg = x` and then a few lines down you tell it `cfg = y` the final value of `cfg` will be the last value assigned. In this example that would be `y`. (Continued....)

Comment: I also see that there is no unique way of firing the function `ChessBoard('board2', cfg);` so that means it will fire on load. (NOTE: I might not fully understand this part since I cannot view the real `ChessBoard` script but..) The first issue would be that although you have 2 seperate `cfg` values it will usually pass the last value assigned. Only why I think this might work the way imagined is because of the order of the code. `cfg` is there first then you fire `ChessBoard` it gets the result and then `cfg` changes and you fire `ChessBoard` again to achieve different results. (Continued...)

Comment: I'll have to do further research into that to see if it is possible but at the same time it seems messing and as a coder you want to thrive toward making code as efficient as possible. I would recommend restructuring the code. If I have more time later I can stop back here and dig into it some more.

Comment: I tried with your solution in the code and it worked! Thanks. Keeping the JS code in the body seems messy, though I have shifted them to the bottom of the page within one script tag. I tried to shift them to an external JS file but it won't work. Maybe it is due to the chessboard() script. Also, I have noticed that external CSS linking is not working. I am using this formula: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css" />. The stylesheet works when kept inside the <style> tags.

Comment: That seems correct, I dont think type is required anymore so this would also work `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" />`. This means that the css folder is located in the root. I'm not sure how your directory is laid out but it should look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/cgohLhU).

Comment: Anytime! Enjoy the rest of your day.